# Mask integer field in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to mask integer field in mysql such that 9999911111 becomes 9900001111. I want to keep first 2 digits and last 4 digits and need to mark rest of the digits as 0 for the integers stored in the field.

I have created a query and it's working but I am not sure whether this is right way to do for integers or not.

```
update table_name 
  set field_name=CONCAT(SUBSTR(field_name, 1, 2), 
                 REPEAT('0', CHAR_LENGTH(field_name) - 6), 
                 SUBSTR(field_name, CHAR_LENGTH(field_name)-3, CHAR_LENGTH(field_name)));
```

Comment: and what does that query do for you?

Comment: this is working fine. But I don't know if that is right way to do for integer fields or not.

Comment: mysql will happily treat your integers as a string, so yeah, i dont see any reason to do anything differently

Answer (score 1):

Just trying a different approach .

```
SET @myVar = 344553543534;
SELECT @myVar  - (SUBSTRING(@myVar, 4, LENGTH(@myVar) - 7) * 10000) ;
```

Above mentioned formula will give 344000003534 as the result. Tried with different combination and found it working.

So your query need to change as given below

```
UPDATE table_name 
  SET field_name= 
 (field_name  - (SUBSTRING(field_name, 4, LENGTH(field_name) - 7) * 10000));
```

Explanation :

```
Consider Number, a =  344553543534;
Expected Result, b =  344000003534;

c = (a - b) = 344553543534 - 344000003534 = 553540000;
```

Now if you consider the result, c, 55354 is the numbers where masking required, and 0000 indicates the last 4 number to be left open.

So to get masked value, we can use the formula, `b = a - c`;

So now to get c, used `SUBSTRING(a, 4, LENGTH(a) - 7) * 10000`

EDIT : To keep only first two numbers, use 3 instead of 4 and 6 instead of 7. I assumed that you needed to keep first 3.

```
SET @myVar = 344553543534;
SELECT @myVar  - (SUBSTRING(@myVar, 3, LENGTH(@myVar) - 6) * 10000) ;
```